# Communicating with a database on multi-chioce button click, using Rails and Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking on line (and on advice from SO, reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html ) but I can't make sense of what it means.

I have a page in my Rails project that has a sequence of bootstrap-styled multi-choice questions. When a user clicks an answer I'd like their record on the 'users' Rails database to be updated. Could someone explain to me the html/erb syntax to enable that?

I know we're not supposed to ask for just code solutions, but I really don't know how to tackle this. For the last few weeks I've been trying almost random things in Rails and ending up asking questions here anyway. If anyone has a working example of what I describe above, that would be great.

If it's helpful, I'm using Bootstrap 3 and Rails 4.1.5

Comment: How is your understanding of the underlying MVC architecture used by Rails?  In essence  You need to have your html/erb/form syntax correct (mVc - view), your controller in place to receive and direct the incoming parameters from your view/form (mvC - controller) and a model prepared and waiting behind the scenes to accept incoming data and save it to the database (Mvc - model).  All three of these pieces need to be in place so that your above scenario will work.  Michael Hartls' Rails Tutorial will give you an excellent introduction to the whole shebang - https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: I can't say I fully understand the overall structure of Rails, but I have the database working, with users able to sign up, and sign in on return. It's updating the database while the application is in use that I don't follow. I have tried reading the Hartls pages but it quickly doesn't make sense to me. Perhaps it's time to stop.

Comment: Keep going - it took me a couple of read through's of that tutorial before the lights flicked on!  It is worth it...

Comment: There just seems to be so much extraneous information! I can't seem to discern which is the information relevant to what I'm trying to do. I understand that the router passes routes and actions to the relevant controller. I DON'T see how individual pages do that, when a user - for example - clicks a button that ISN'T a link to a separate page.